# android - app crashes when saving photograph

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I've been following the camera guide from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Everything works until after I have taken the photograph and selected the tick to accept the image. Then I get the dreaded 'unfortunately app has stopped working'. I'm testing on a real nexus 5 device.

My code is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
} 


private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private Uri fileUri;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

/* Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "SimpleCamera");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("SimpleCamera", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

public void openCamera(View view){
    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                     data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
}
```

In my manifest I have included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

My Logcat

```
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487): Process: com.juliette.simplecamera, PID: 21487
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.juliette.simplecamera/com.juliette.simplecamera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at com.juliette.simplecamera.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:94)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
03-20 12:40:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
```

And my layout just in case

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.juliette.simplecamera.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="@string/camera" 
    android:onClick="openCamera"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know the issue is something to do with returning to the original activity with the result but I have no idea how to resolve this. Any suggestions would be appreciated, I'm quite new at this and I'm assuming I've made a simple rookie mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is line number 94 of your MainActivity.java class?

Comment: I think `Intent data` is `null` in `onActivityResult()`...

Comment: it's data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); from the toast

Comment: data is null.Check the below answers.

Comment: Thank you everyone, simple fix that would likely taken me a few more hours of frustration. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your logcat below like it clearly indicates that your `Intent data` is `null`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null}
```

Check for the null value of the `Intent` data.

Try out as below:

```
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                 data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Some times we will receive `null` data even though result is successfull i.e. resultcode is `Activity.RESULT_OK`. so validating with `Intent data` is not a way here.

Comment: That works! Thank you very much, I knew it would be something simple

Answer (score 3):

In this line occurring the crash...because, `data` is `null`.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This line saying that `data` is `null`...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null}
```

So, when you are trying to get data using `getData()` method from `Intent` object `data` then `NullPointerException`  occurring.

To prevent this `Exception`, check that `data` isn't `null` before trying to get data as below...

```
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if(data != null) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                     data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```